# WPF MVVM Report Viewer

Tags: wpf, mvvm, reportviewer

I was able to print report using Report Viewer (using [Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WinForms/) package) in my WPF app. But I'm doing it on code behind. I had this [post](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ReportViewer-control-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) as a reference. My concern now is, is it possible to bind the report viewer in the View to a View Model?

Below is my current implementation. But I want to retain the MVVM way of WPF.

This is my view: MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Here's the Code-behind for printing reports: MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
DataTable openReports = GetReports();
ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", openReports);

PageSettings ps = new PageSettings();
ps.Landscape = true;
ps.Margins = new Margins(50, 50, 50, 50);
ps.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170);
ps.PaperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;
this.reportViewer.SetPageSettings(ps);
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports.rdlc";
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();

GetReports(); //method for getting data from database to populate reports.
```

Thank you! :)

Edit:
What I did was bind a content presenter to a Windows Form Host in my View Model and it's working fine! Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: If you want to use the `ReportViewer` with `DataBinding` etc. you will need to write a wrapper class since the `ReportViewer` on its own doesn't support it. Don't know if someone didn't publish something like that already, might be worth looking for one.

Comment: What things are you trying to "Bind" to the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Wrap it in a UserControl.  Bind whatever to DependencyProperties on the UC, and in the property changed event handler update the report control.  UI logic is perfectly fine in codebehind.